# Validity of Linear Response Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory, correlation-functions

Suppose the perturbation of the hamiltonian is some multiple of the free hamiltonian, that is 
$$H=H_0+H_1=H_0+\lambda H_0=(1+\lambda)H_0.$$
Here, certain operators apparently have no response due to this "Pertubation", for example the response of the average value of $H_0$ goes as $[H_0,H_0]=0$ (Think spin response in magnetic field) which should not be true intuitively. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Your new Hamiltonian is diagonal in the old Hamiltonian’s eigenstates. So there will be no response as such. Every state remains in the same state as energy eigenstates form a basis. The only things that change are the energy eigenvalue that are now scaled by $1+\lambda$.

Comment: However think of the case of a spin particle in a magnetic field. One would expect that in finite temperature the average spin of the particle is proportional to the magnetic field, but this tells us the response would be 0 if we think of changes in the field as a perturbation.

Comment: Is the Hamiltonian of the form $\mu S\cdot B$?

Comment: Yeah, I meant an Hamiltonian of that form. A $z$ magnetic field.

Comment: You just use regular statistical mechanics (density matrix) to get the single particle partition function and find the expectation values. We know the energy levels and they depend on the magnitude of $\vec B$. Since the energy levels are changing (with $B$), so will the expectation values.

Comment: Yes I know that method works. But treating a change in the  magnetic field as a perturbation, and using linear response theory doesn't work. I wanted to know why.

Comment: Because the response of the system to this change is only in scaling the spacing between the energy levels. It is not resulting in any crosstalk between the states. This means that any state maintains itself. All inner products are preserved.